# Does example of Erwin Unruh work today?

Tags: c++, g++, template-meta-programming

Here is the [example](http://www.zolix.hu/ch06s04.html) from `Erwin Unruh` famous for using `C++` template meta-programming to produce the prime number in the compiler error message as follow.

```
// Erwin Unruh, untitled program, 
// ANSI X3J16-94-0075/ISO WG21-462, 1994.

template <int i>
struct D
{
    D(void *);
    operator int();
};

template <int p, int i>
struct is_prime
{
    enum { prim = (p%i) && is_prime<(i>2?p:0), i>::prim };
};

template <int i>
struct Prime_print
{
    Prime_print<i-1>    a;
    enum { prim = is_prime<i,i-1>::prim };
    void f() { D<i> d = prim; }
};

struct is_prime<0,0> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
struct is_prime<0,1> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
struct Prime_print<2>
{
    enum { prim = 1 };
    void f() { D<2> d = prim; }
};

void foo()
{
    Prime_print<10> a;
}
```

The result is expected to be this compiler error message:

```
// output:
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<2> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<3> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<5> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<7> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<11> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<13> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<17> requested in Prime_print
// unruh.cpp 30: conversion from enum to D<19> requested in Prime_print
```

I checked this code and compiled it via `g++` and did not get the same result.

Despite I used `c++17` via

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp
```

it seems that even `c++03` does not work either. The result is nothing similar to what is expected. Should I use different compiler options?

```
main.cpp:25:1: error: an explicit specialization must be preceded by ‘template <>’
 struct is_prime<0,0> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 template <> 
main.cpp:26:1: error: an explicit specialization must be preceded by ‘template <>’
 struct is_prime<0,1> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 template <> 
main.cpp:27:1: error: an explicit specialization must be preceded by ‘template <>’
 struct Prime_print<2>
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 template <> 
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Prime_print<2>::f()’:
main.cpp:30:25: error: conversion from ‘Prime_print<2>::<unnamed enum>’ to non-scalar type ‘D<2>’ requested
     void f() { D<2> d = prim; }
                         ^~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<0, 2>’:
main.cpp:14:25:   required from ‘struct is_prime<3, 2>’
main.cpp:20:25:   recursively required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<0, 2>’ used in nested name specifier
     enum { prim = (p%i) && is_prime<(i>2?p:0), i>::prim };
                   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<4, 3>’:
main.cpp:20:25:   recursively required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<4, 3>’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<5, 4>’:
main.cpp:20:25:   recursively required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<5, 4>’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<6, 5>’:
main.cpp:20:25:   recursively required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<6, 5>’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<7, 6>’:
main.cpp:20:25:   recursively required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<7, 6>’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<8, 7>’:
main.cpp:20:25:   recursively required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<8, 7>’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<9, 8>’:
main.cpp:21:10:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<9>’
main.cpp:20:25:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<9, 8>’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_prime<10, 9>’:
main.cpp:21:10:   required from ‘struct Prime_print<10>’
main.cpp:35:21:   required from here
main.cpp:14:25: error: incomplete type ‘is_prime<10, 9>’ used in nested name specifier
```

---

**Update 1**

There is an [alternative code](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=KFdCCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1527&lpg=PT1527&dq=Prime_print&source=bl&ots=iPxX9D90HL&sig=Vqti-jwoBG_J0VjRDJ_rdFFfIXQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDuPa0-67ZAhWFTLwKHTiGDroQ6AEIZjAJ#v=onepage&q=Prime_print&f=false) as suggested by user `Tony Delroy`. I tried this code and it didn't work either.

```
template <int i>
struct D
{
    D(void *);
    operator int();
};

template <int p, int i>
struct is_prime
{
    enum { prim = (p==2) || (p%i) && is_prime<(i>2?p:0), i-1>::prim };
};

template <int i>
struct Prime_print
{
    Prime_print<i-1>    a;
    enum { prim = is_prime<i,i-1>::prim };
    void f() { D<i> d = prim ? 1 : 0; a.f(); }
};

struct is_prime<0,0> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
struct is_prime<0,1> { enum { prim = 1 }; };

struct Prime_print<2>
{
    enum { prim = 0 };
    void f() { D<1> d = prim? 1 : 0; }
};

int main()
{
    Prime_print<18> a;
    a.f()
}
```

---

**Update 2**

I found a working code [here](https://gitlab.ethz.ch/pt1_hs17/lecture/blob/4294851cacfbcc2fcc40b60cfeedcf5b5c9a7197/demos/week11/unruh_new.cpp).
The only problem is that it should be cascaded with `grep` to give result

```
g++ -std=c++03 -c -fpermissive main.cpp 2>&1 | grep "In instantiation"
```

Output:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 17]’:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 13]’:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 11]’:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 7]’:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 5]’:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 3]’:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Prime_print<i>::f() [with int i = 2]’:
```

Is there any way to produce single line errors without using Linux `grep` command?

```
/*
  Prime number computation by Erwin Unruh
  http://www.erwin-unruh.de/Prim.html
  compatible with (now!) "valid" C++
  compile --> the error messages are the prime numbers up to 18!
  for clang: c++ unruh_new.cpp 2>&1 | grep -i error
  for gnu:   g++-mp-5 -std=c++03 -c                                \
                      -fpermissive                                 \
                      unruh_new.cpp 2>&1 | grep "In instantiation"
*/

template <int i> struct D { D(void*); operator int(); };

template <int p, int i> struct is_prime {
 enum { prim = (p==2) || (p%i) && is_prime<(i>2?p:0), i-1> :: prim };
};

template <int i> struct Prime_print {
 Prime_print<i-1> a;
 enum { prim = is_prime<i, i-1>::prim };
 void f() { D<i> d = prim ? 1 : 0; a.f();}
};

template<> struct is_prime<0,0> { enum {prim=1}; };
template<> struct is_prime<0,1> { enum {prim=1}; };

template<> struct Prime_print<1> {
 enum {prim=0};
 void f() { D<1> d = prim ? 1 : 0; };
};

#ifndef LAST
#define LAST 18
#endif

main() {
 Prime_print<LAST> a;
 a.f();
}
```

Comment: Notice the date on the first program. 1994 predates even C++98. His template specialization is very much non-standard, but it worked on some experimental compilers.

Answer (score 3):

Below you'll find the update program I use in my C++ lectures. It runs perfectly well (i.e., it produces errors ;-) ) even with g++-8 --std=c++2a. To try it out I suggest to use the following script: w/o argument you get the primes until 25, with a numeric argument (e.g., 100) you get the primes until 100. The output is filtered through sed, showing the important lines. If you want all of the compiler's output provide any 2nd argument.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    last=25
else
    last=$1
fi

if [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
   g++ --std=c++2a -DLAST=${last} primefrank.cc |& less
else
    (g++ --std=c++2a -DLAST=${last} primefrank.cc 2>&1) |
                                   grep 'instantiation of' |
                                   sed 's/ instantiation of//'
fi
```

Here is the prorgram's source:

```
#ifndef LAST
#define LAST 18
#endif

enum 
{
    IS_PRIME,
    NO_PRIME,
    CONTINUE  
};

template <int candidate, int testValue>
struct Eval
{
    enum
    { 
        mode = 
            testValue * testValue > candidate ? IS_PRIME  :    
            candidate % testValue == 0 ?        NO_PRIME  :
                                                CONTINUE
    };
};

template <int candidate, int prime, int mode >
struct sieve
{
    enum 
    { 
        next = prime + 1,
        isPrime = sieve<candidate, next, 
                        Eval<candidate, next>::mode>::isPrime
    };
};

template <int candidate, int prime> 
struct sieve<candidate, prime, IS_PRIME>
{
    enum { isPrime = IS_PRIME };
};

template <int candidate, int prime>
struct sieve<candidate, prime, NO_PRIME >
{
    enum { isPrime = NO_PRIME };
};

template <int prime>
struct test
{
    enum {isPrime = sieve<prime, 2, Eval<prime, 2>::mode>::isPrime };
};

template <int prime, int isPrime>
struct show
{                           
    static void f()
    {
        show<prime - 1, test<prime - 1>::isPrime >::f();
    }
};

template <int prime>
struct show<prime, IS_PRIME>
{
    static int *f()
    {
        show<prime - 1, test<prime - 1>::isPrime >::f();

        int x;
        return &x;
    }
};

template <>
struct show<1, IS_PRIME>
{
    static void f()
    {}
};

template <int prime>
void primes()
{
    show<prime, test<prime>::isPrime>::f();
}

int main() 
{
    // 'instantiation' messages because of the suggested grep command
    static_assert(LAST >= 2, 
        "instantiation of LAST must be >= 2");
    
    primes<LAST>();

    static_assert(0, 
        "instantiation of compilation terminated");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching online, [a preview](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=KFdCCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1527&lpg=PT1527&dq=Prime_print&source=bl&ots=iPxX9D90HL&sig=Vqti-jwoBG_J0VjRDJ_rdFFfIXQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDuPa0-67ZAhWFTLwKHTiGDroQ6AEIZjAJ#v=onepage&q=Prime_print&f=false) of the book Discovering Modern C++ lists slightly different source code in `struct is_prime`:

```
enum { prim = (p == 2) || (p%i) etc...
```

The next page lists a whole lot of errors like the ones you document, and the page after shows compiler output that lists the prime more succinctly:

```
error: initializing argument 1 of ...whatever... [ with int i = 17 ]
error: initializing argument 1 of ...whatever... [ with int i = 13 ]
...and so on...
```

So - I suggest looking at your error messages more carefully.  Still, how the errors are reported depends on your compiler and can legitimately vary with version, so it's not wrong for the compiler not to produce what you expect.

Comment: It doens't  work as well. I have updated the question too.